# How to use different web.xml descriptor in tomcat7-maven-plugin:run?

Tags: maven, tomcat, maven-tomcat-plugin, embedded-tomcat-7

I would like to have two different `web.xml` descriptor files in my maven project. First (default) should be included in war file for deployment to application server and second should be used for development using `tomcat7-maven-plugin:run`. I know there is `<tomcatWebXml>` parameter but it specifies Tomcat global `web.xml` which I don't want to change.

For `jetty-maven-plugin:run` I can specify either `<webApp>/<descriptor>` or `<webApp>/<overrideDescriptor>`. First replaces default `web.xml` with specified file while second applies specified file content in addition to default `web.xml`.

Is there some possibility how to achieve same functionality with `tomcat7-maven-plugin`?

Comment: Could you elaborate why `tomcatWebXml` is no good for you?

Comment: Parameter `<tomcatWebXml>` overrides Tomcat global web.xml file. In fact I want to use the original file which is released as part of Tomcat. And I also don't want to copy&paste this 150KB long file to my `web.xml` file.

Answer (score 2):

It is an old question, but I will write this here in case anyone else is looking.

Yes, it is possible.

You can do this by overriding the default (built-in) war-builder that tomcat7-maven-plugin uses, which is org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin
The override is done by simply adding that plugin to your pom.xml, along with the extra configuration `webXml`

The code will look like this

```
    <plugins>
        ...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <webXml>myPath/web.xml</webXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                ... other configurations here
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        ...
    </plugins>
```

Comment: Good idea but I needed two web.xml files, default for deployment to application server and second for tomcat. This could be done by moving your maven-war-plugin configuration to maven profile. But then developers would have to specify this profile each time they run tomcat.